# Chain iterators to references of different lifetimies

Tags: rust, iterator, lifetime, chain

I want to build a recursive function for traversing a tree in Rust. The function should always get the next element and an iterator over references to the ancestor elements.

For the iterator over ancestor elements, one could in principle use the `chain` and `once` methods. Consider the following simple example, where the tree is jsut a Vec (for the purpose of this demonstration):

```
fn proceed<'a, I>(mut remaining: Vec<String>, ancestors: I)
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a String> + Clone,
{
    if let Some(next) = remaining.pop() {
        let next_ancestors = ancestors.chain(std::iter::once(&next));
        proceed(remaining, next_ancestors);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7d40d1cd97f2a9f9b1a73121122cd250)

This fails to compile because `&next` has a shorter lifetime than `'a`:

```
error[E0597]: `next` does not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:6:62
  |
1 | fn proceed<'a, I>(mut remaining: Vec<String>, ancestors: I)
  |            -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
6 |         let next_ancestors = ancestors.chain(std::iter::once(&next));
  |                              --------------------------------^^^^^--
  |                              |                               |
  |                              |                               borrowed value does not live long enough
  |                              argument requires that `next` is borrowed for `'a`
7 |         proceed(remaining, next_ancestors);
8 |     }
  |     - `next` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I tried to overcome this by adding an explicit second lifetime `'b: 'a` and forcing an explicit reference by something like `let next_ref: &'b String = &next`, but that yields a (different) error message as well.

One solution I came up with was to call `map` as follows:

```
let next_ancestors = ancestors.map(|r| r).chain(std::iter::once(&next));
```

As pointed out by @trentcl, this [doesn't actually solve the problem](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=59adce22a4da9966d81b22465eace5b1), as the compiler then gets stuck in an infinite loop when compiling `proceed` for all the nested `Chain`s when one actually tries to call the function.

Comment: You are in a maze of twisty little compiler errors, all different. If I [fix the first error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cf8e1eee47f665cf7f37fefadffeaf3c), everything seems OK at first, but if you try to call `proceed` anywhere the compiler will try to compute an infinite type (because in order to compile `proceed<I>` you must first compile `proceed<Chain<I, Once<String>>>`, and in order to compile *that* you must first compile `proceed<Chain<Chain<I, Once<String>>, Once<String>>>`, etc. Now, you could "fix" this problem with dynamic dispatch...

Comment: ... but it just pushes you further into the maze: `ancestors` can't be allowed to borrow from `remaining`, since you're traversing the `Vec` destructively, so you can't apply the same strategy to iterating over a tree by reference. I'm not sure how best to answer this question because fixing the current compiler error clearly doesn't solve the problem. I strongly suggest you take a step back and reevaluate how you got here; there's likely to be a simpler solution. (Read [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/), if you haven't already.)

Answer (score 1):

The pieces of solution are already around, just to summarize:

As you already know, using `map(|r| r)` "decouples" the lifetime requirement of `ancestors`
from the lifetime of `&next`.

As already stated in the comments, fixing 
the infinite recursion is a matter to change `ancestors` into a trait object.

```
fn proceed<'a>(mut remaining: Vec<String>, ancestors: &mut dyn Iterator<Item = &'a String>) {
    if let Some(next) = remaining.pop() {
        let mut next_ancestors = ancestors.map(|r| r).chain(std::iter::once(&next));
        proceed(remaining, &mut next_ancestors);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string()];
    proceed(v, &mut std::iter::empty());
}
```